# Sending a message from Azure Logic App Workflow to Azure Service Bus - can the JSON event data be "pruned"?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-eventgrid

I'm still quite new to this, but I've spent hours searching for a solution and can't find so much as a mention of if this is even possible.

Currently, I have an Azure Logic App workflow triggering on certain Azure Event Grid events, and I send the JSON event data to an Azure Service Bus queue and to my Inbox (while I'm testing).

If possible, I'd like to select specific JSON keypairs (or subkeys) to output, rather than the entire JSON event data. I know there are functions available, or raw code, so I feel like it's maybe possible, but way outside of my skill set.

For example, many of the events have the name of the person who initiated the event, and I'd like to pull out just that data from the JSON and ignore most of the rest.

Example: `{"claims":{"name":"Doe, John"}})`

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured out how to do what I want.
There is a step "Parse JSON" that can be added. I put that step before my "send a message" step, and gave it a sample JSON from the event and it figured it out automatically!
I then can construct my own JSON with just the keypairs I want, in the message content I'm sending to the Service Bus.
Preliminary testing seems to work as expected.